# How to parse key's uisng .format in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to fetch the value from a dictionary using .format

```
test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value= test_dict[{}].format(input_value)

print(value)
```

But it throw the error says

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

i am not able to find a solution to this simple progam

Comment: Why not just `test_dict[input_value]`?. I don't see any application of `format` function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct format:

```
test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value= test_dict['{}'.format(input_value)]

print(value)

#John
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it was necessary to build the key in this way, but the efficiency tests I conducted showed that this is the most ineffective way.

```
import sys
sys.version # 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0]
```

Test1 (`format`):

```
%%timeit

test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value = test_dict['{}'.format(input_value)]

# 191 ns ± 32.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Test (% Operator):

```
%%timeit

test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value = test_dict['%s' % input_value]

# 154 ns ± 43.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Test (`f-string`):

```
%%timeit

test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value = test_dict[f'{input_value}']

# 123 ns ± 19.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Test (without string formating):

```
%%timeit

test_dict={'name':'John'}

input_value='name'
value = test_dict[input_value]

# 96.8 ns ± 1.48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```